# Type 'AnimationController' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, custom-transition

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum TransitionType {
   case Presenting, Dismissing
}

class AnimationController: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
   var duration: NSTimeInterval
   var isPresenting: Bool
   var originFrame: CGRect

   init(withDuration duration: NSTimeInterval, forTransitionType type: TransitionType, originFrame: CGRect) {
      self.duration = duration
      self.isPresenting = type == .Presenting
      self.originFrame = originFrame

      super.init()
   }

   func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
       return self.duration
   }
}
```

The code was adapted from the below tutorial:

- [How to Create Custom View Controller Transitions and Animations](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-view-controller-transitions-and-animations--cms-25716)

Comment: Always is a good tip make Command+Click inside the delegate and see what function are mandatory for the protocol, not marked as `optional` and see what's missing

Answer (score 1):

It's what the error says. The code hasn't fully adopted the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol. You need to implement `public func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`, which happens in the next block of code in the article you linked to.